# Trying to build liquidsoap libportaudio not found

Tags: linux, opensuse-12.2, liquidsoap

I'm trying to build **liquidsoap** on **openSuse 12.2**. ./configure is stuck at :

```
configure: error: libportaudio not found
```

However, when I tried installing from rpm:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh libportaudio2-19_20111121-2.1.2.i586.rpm
```

The message i get is:

```
package libportaudio2-19_20111121-2.1.2.i586 is already installed
```

What's wrong? Should I be installing another package, which liquidsoap needs?

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I redressed that, I agree it can only be the work of someone who deeply misunderstands the use of downvoting.